# valid prop not works in the styled-component. It gives a warning

Tags: reactjs, validation, styled-components, prop

When the input is invalid, `ErrorMassage` should be shown. But not works, and warning about `valid` prop **(unresolved variable valid)**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from "styled-components";

const Div = styled.div``;
const Input = styled.input``;
const ErrorMessage = styled.p`
   display: ${props => props.valid ? 'block' : 'none'};
`;

function App(){
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [validity, setValidity] = useState(false);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
        setValidity(e.target.checkValidity() ? false : true);
    }
    return(
    <>
        <Div>
        <Input
        value = {value}
        onChange = {handleChange}
        >
        </Input>
        </Div>
        <ErrorMessage valid={validity}>Error</ErrorMessage>
    </>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-fast-df2qt

Note to warning:

[image]

Comment: Your boolean check looks backwards - `props => props.valid ? 'block' : 'none'` - this will set the display propery to `block` when valid is `true` - shouldn't that be the other way around?

Comment: Is that the correct sandbox link? It appears to be a brand-new, untouched React Code Sandbox.

Comment: @gerrod Yes and it is not working. it warned about `valid`.

Answer (score 0):

#### shouldForwardProp

As the type error explained, valid is a invalid prop. You should use `shouldForwardProp` in your styled component so the `valid` prop does not get passed down to the `p` element.

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop

```
const ErrorMessage = styled('p', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'valid'})`
  display: ${(props) => (props.valid ? "block" : "none")};
`;
```

And your following check...

```
 setValidity(e.target.checkValidity() ? false : true);
```

Is the above really what you want? You will probably just want to set it to the following, which is the proper code style and naming.

```
 setValidity(e.target.checkValidity());
```

#### your styled component

This also brings to your styled component which is also, wrong (IMO)

```
display: ${(props) => (props.valid ? "block" : "none")};
```

should probably be, the following, since you only want to display when `valid === false`

```
display: ${(props) => (props.valid ? "none" : "block")};
```

Comment: Thanks. I did two last changing, but `{ shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'valid'}` for what? also says: `Unused property shouldForwardProp`. also again warned about `valid`(Unresolved variable valid).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, though it's just a workaround I accidentally found.

Replace `props.valid` with `props['valid']` and the result should be something like this:

```
display: ${props => props['valid'] ? 'block' : 'none'};
```